# NetStream Object Buffer fails to fill and video just freezes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, netstream

I'm hoping someone has some insight into this as this is driving me nuts.  I have a Net Stream object that I am using to stream video from an Amazon Flash Media Streaming service.

The video makes a connection and plays fine but randomly it seems to just freeze and the only way to get it to work again is to re-establish the connection.  I have tried to put other videos in that amazon bucket as well and they seem to play fine.  this happens when it is in .FLV form and .mp4 format.

I have set the buffer time to be 5 seconds and i watch the output of the buffer to see the % of full it is.  when the problem occurs the buffer 5 goes from 100 to 0 and then it throws a Buffer fail error (i'm using OVP framework).

I have come to the conclusion that it is either a video encoding problem or perhaps there is a firewall issue that blocks the data from getting through.

Has anyone ever had any issue with this and if so how did you resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not really a great solution but what I wound up doing is

checking the buffer percentage and when the buffer indicates that it is loaded less than 20% I just trigger a re-connection. (OVP has a property called bufferPercentage, but its just a calculation of NetStream.bufferLength/NetStream.bufferTime). I also save the ns.time so that when I call play after re-connecting I tell it to start at the point where it left off.

Not an ideal solution but it seems to have at least offered an alternative to a freezing video stream.

This might be an isolated incident as I was using the Open video Player, but i've used this library several times without any issues along with the Amazon S3 Flash Streaming server. http://openvideoplayer.sourceforge.net/ovpfl/docs/asdocs-fp10/index.html